# Form control: Pristine attribute is not being updated?

Tags: javascript, html, css, angular, typescript

I am trying to create some simple form validation around 2 input boxes and a button. When these input field boxes are empty (pristine) I want the button to be disabled. When either box has a value I want the button to be able to submit. Currently, when the input fields are first rendered the pristine attribute is true. When a change has been made in the boxes it is set to false but when the changes are deleted I want it to go back to false, however Angular does not seem to reset this validation?

Comment: `<button [disabled]="!form.valid">` and by saying so your controls need to have validators at least the required one

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Pristine doesn't mean "empty", it means "the user hasn't changed the value since it was displayed in this form". Use the field's `value` attribute instead, like

```
<button [disabled]="!myField1.value?.length && !myField2.value?.length">
```

https://angular.io/guide/forms

But this is a shortcut, and if you want to make either of two inputs required (and simply disable submit when the form is invalid), look at this thread:

[Require one from two fields using Angular 2](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41020069/require-one-from-two-fields-using-angular-2)

Comment: Whlie I agree, there's more efficient than that, which is the `required` attribute.

Comment: Generally, you're right. Specifically, with _either of two inputs_ required, as in this story, it gets a little more tricky.

Comment: Indeed, you would have to make a form validation instead of a control one. But it would be more flexible, since you could validate other things (min-max length, patterns ...), while this answer validates only the non-emptiness. I upvoted it though, since it does answer the question !