# Angular forms require one of two form groups to be valid

Tags: javascript, html, angular, angular-reactive-forms, angular-validation

I am trying to implement a reactive angular form where either A or B has to be entered. A is a unique id and B is a set of values which identify the id. Now I try to validate a Form that is valid if either A is entered or B is entered including all the required values. I found several solutions that implement this behavior based on FormFields but was not able to get it working with the group of values.

```html
<form class="container" [formGroup]="myForm" (ngSubmit)="onSubmit()">
      <mat-form-field class="w-1/2">
        <mat-label>ID</mat-label>
        <input matInput type="number" formControlName="id">
      </mat-form-field>

      <div class="grid grid-cols-3 gap-4" formGroupName="innerGroup">
        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>First Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="number" formControlName="firstName">
        </mat-form-field>

        <mat-form-field>
          <mat-label>Last Name</mat-label>
          <input matInput type="number" formControlName="lastName">
        </mat-form-field>
      </div>
</form>
```

My first idea was to override the default validator for the form but I could not figure out how to do that. Not even sure if it would be possible. I was trying to adjust https://stackoverflow.com/a/48714721 to work in my scenario but I had no idea how to get it to work because of the additional complexity with the inner form group.

Answer (score 1):

Using angular 14 I was able to produce a similar result to what you are describing I am not sure it will 100% solve your issue however it might help.

Basically what I did was create a validator function that is to be applied at the group level. This validator will check the `valid` state of any given controls be they a `FormGroup` or a `FormControl`. However, this alone will not solve the problem as if you have a form group angular will see that any underling control or group that is invalid will also invalidate the parent. So what I did was call `.disable()` on any control that was being checked by the validator function. This will disable the UI element and disable validation checking by angular allowing the parent to be considered valid when one of the children is valid but the other is invalid effectively creating a `one and only one` validator.

My specific example I was trying to get the `OnlyOneValidator` to work for a `MatStepper`.

## Validator

```
export function onlyOneValidator(controlKeys: string[]) {
    return (control: AbstractControl): ValidationErrors | null => {
        let countOfValidControls = 0;
        for (let key of controlKeys) {
            const controlToCheck = control.get(key);

            if (controlToCheck === null || controlToCheck === undefined) {
                throw new Error(`Error: Invalid control key specified key was ${key}`);
            }

            countOfValidControls += controlToCheck?.valid ? 1 : 0;
        }

        if (countOfValidControls !== 1) {
            // the count is not exactly one
            return {
                onlyOneValid: {
                    actualValidCount: countOfValidControls,
                    expectedValidCount: 1
                }
            };
        }

        return null;
    };
}
```

## Controller

```
@Component({
    selector: "app-equipment-creation-page",
    templateUrl: "./equipment-creation-page.component.html",
    styleUrls: ["./equipment-creation-page.component.scss"],
})
export class EquipmentCreationPageComponent implements OnInit, OnDestroy {
    public categories = [null, "Tools", "Vehicles"];

    constructor(private _formBuilder: FormBuilder) {}


    public categoryInformationGroup = this._formBuilder.group({
        existingCategory: this._formBuilder.group({
            category: new FormControl(null, [ Validators.required ])
        }),
        newCategory: this._formBuilder.group({
            name: new FormControl("", [Validators.required]),
            description: new FormControl("", [Validators.required])
        })
    }, {
        validators: [
            onlyOneValidator(["existingCategory", "newCategory"])
        ],
    });

    public ngOnDestroy(): void {
        this.subscriptions.forEach(sub => {
            sub.unsubscribe();
        });
    }

    private subscriptions: Subscription[] = [];
    public ngOnInit(): void {
        this.subscriptions.push(this.categoryInformationGroup.controls.existingCategory.statusChanges.pipe(
            tap((status: string) => {
                if (status === "VALID") {
                    this.categoryInformationGroup.controls.newCategory.disable();
                } else {
                    this.categoryInformationGroup.controls.newCategory.enable();
                }
            })
        ).subscribe());

        this.subscriptions.push(this.categoryInformationGroup.controls.newCategory.statusChanges.pipe(
            tap((status: string) => {
                if (status === "VALID") {
                    this.categoryInformationGroup.controls.existingCategory.disable();
                } else {
                    this.categoryInformationGroup.controls.existingCategory.enable();
                }
            })
        ).subscribe());
    }
}
```

## Template

```html
<form [formGroup]="categoryInformationGroup.controls.existingCategory">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Apply to existing category?</mat-label>
    <mat-select formControlName="category">
      <mat-option *ngFor="let category of categories" [value]="category">
        {{ category ?? "None" }}
      </mat-option>
    </mat-select>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>

OR

<form [formGroup]="categoryInformationGroup.controls.newCategory">
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Create New Category</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="name" placeholder="Name">
    <mat-error *ngIf="categoryInformationGroup.controls.newCategory.controls.name.hasError('required')">This field
      is required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
  <mat-form-field>
    <mat-label>Create New Category</mat-label>
    <input matInput formControlName="description" placeholder="Description">
    <mat-error *ngIf="categoryInformationGroup.controls.newCategory.controls.description.hasError('required')">
      This field is required
    </mat-error>
  </mat-form-field>
</form>
```

Hopefully this helps or at least gives you some ideas about how to approach this. If anyone else has any thoughts on this please let me know I would love to find a better way to do this.